# summing integer64 columns not doing what I expect

Tags: r, data.table

I do not understand what is going on here.  Why does sum work outside of data.table and not inside it? data.table version is 1.94 and bit64 is loaded.

```
 
dput(dt)
structure(list(Date = c(20150422L, 20150422L, 20150422L, 20150422L,
20150423L, 20150423L, 20150423L, 20150423L, 20150424L, 20150424L,
20150424L, 20150424L), totcap = structure(c(5.30519039464278e-314,
5.34352625144878e-314, 5.21151503979773e-314, 5.18159473949947e-314,
5.36659973716195e-314, 5.3767197559193e-314, 5.31749562227391e-314,
5.48717086915892e-314, 5.34891674084389e-314, 5.22243170680067e-314,
5.22969347328787e-314, 5.23636617172838e-314), class = "integer64")), .Names = c("Date",
"totcap"), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA,
-12L), .internal.selfref = )

> sum(dt$totcap)
integer64
[1] 128782928014

> dt[,sum(totcap),by=Date]
       Date            V1
1: 20150422 2.104183e-313
2: 20150423 2.154799e-313
3: 20150424 2.103741e-313
```

Comment: In the devel version `v1.9.5` it is working `dt[,sum(totcap),by=Date]$V1#
integer64
[1] 42589130822 43613609175 42580188017`

Comment: what do you think is best workaround for 1.94?  fread(..., integer64="numeric")? I only get integer64s because i use fread.

Comment: for now you could use `bit64::sum.integer64(totcap)`...